# Python Jupyter won't show output of graphs even when %matplotlib inline is added

Tags: python, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook

so I asked this question a while ago but still found no solution. So I am still a beginner in Python and started to play around with graphs. But no matter what kind of graphs I do, I can't get any graphs to show in the notebook.

The kernel keeps loading and as you can see in the last In[*], it keeps on staying like that without showing the result. 
Anyone can help me with this? Thanks!

I am including the screenshot here:

[image]

Comment: not quite sure, but maybe put the `%matplotlib inline` after the import? Also, first try with a really easy plot like `plt.plot([1,2,3])`

Comment: @user8408080 ah you're right! should've put it after the import. But it still loaded a long time though

Comment: I would expect it to take awhile to load the plot with a `43776x6` CSV to parse and create a figure from